# Is "Streets with poor pavement" generally correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

Can we say:

> Streets that have poor pavements

Or

> Streets having poor pavement

Instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are talking about **streets** in the plural, then I think it needs to be **pavements** in the plural.

The slight complication is that **pavement** means slightly different things in UK and US English.

In the UK, **pavement** is the solid, usually raised, area on either side of the street. (This is the **sidewalk** in the US.) This would need to be plural (pavements) in your sentence.

In the US, **pavement** is the hard surface of the street itself. This is uncountable and would need to be singular (pavement) in your sentence.

Comment: In the US, we would just say "pavement", too, because it's a mass noun, like "Beaches have *sand*", and not "Beaches have *sands*."

Comment: I haven't heard "pavement" used that way in the UK. When I was there 45 years ago, they used the term "footpath" or just "path." Is there some regional usage variation?

Comment: @BobRodes Here is a definition that fits my understanding of the word: [British 1 A raised paved or asphalted path for pedestrians at the side of a road.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pavement). To me a footpath is a purely pedestrian path, possibly paved, through a garden, a field, woods, etc.

Comment: @JamesRandom I wasn't aware of that, and thanks for linking the dictionary definition. Yes, they used the term footpath or path to mean something like a path through the woods as well, what we Americans would call a path. I thought it a bit strange when I first got there (age 13) and heard everyone calling the sidewalk the path (right up there with calling the ground outside the "floor"), except -- of course -- our teachers who called it the footpath. But I don't recall hearing the sidewalk referred to as the pavement. Interesting.

Comment: @BobRodes Maybe it is a regional thing. Where were you?

Answer (score 2):

Why not say: poorly paved streets?

Is that what is actually meant? The paving in the streets is not adequate or good enough.

A pavement or sidewalk is different:

Streets with  inadequate pavements or sidewalks.

Somehow, I think  you mean the first.

Comment: thank you. your answer really helped. I'm just curious is 'Streets having poor pavement' correct?

Comment: Street with poor pavements/pavement and poor paving are common in some counties in the state of Texas. :0

Comment: Is  'Streets having poor pavement' grammatically correct either?

Comment: It depends on many factors. Something can be grammatically correct and stylistically poor English (or any language). It is not wrong but it could be very awkward.